# How to render an html response from an api in Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I am calling a 3rd party api and it is supposed to return an html response. How can i render such response or is there another better way to deal with this?

Comment: You might need to provide a little more detail. My first thought would be to take the API response, and use that data as the model for a gsp render.

Comment: its an html response though so i dont know how or why to put it in a model.
what i mean by html response is 
<200, <html> <head>....</head><body>........</body> 
how can i render such response?

Comment: Trebla provided an example below, but here are more examples from the documentation: https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html

Answer (score 0):

If it's returning an HTML String, just render that directly (assuming you don't want to do anything with it).  It's not clear to me this is actually what's happening, but if so...

```
def someAction() {
  String htmlResponse = <api call>      
  render htmlResponse
}
```

Comment: If there's a script in the response, that script will execute...  it's just creating an HTML page

Comment: but the js is not cdn im not sure it will execute.. but i will try this  after i fix my errors.